# What can I do to improve my coding on both html and css

Tags: html, css

I've been coding for awhile now and I was wondering what I could do to be more efficient when it comes to coding or any advice of what I'm doing incorrect. I think the things I can probably point out right off the bat is my misuse of width on majority of the tags. I also remember reading something that I should be using input instead of button but am not exactly sure. Thanks for taking your time reviewing my code!  [Photo of my coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtdIa.png)

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    .list-of-friends {
  display: block;
  border: solid;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left:30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.profile-picture {
  display: inline-block;
}
.profile-picture, .user-name, follow-button {
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
p, button {
  font-family: Arial;
}
.oliver-profile, .mimi-profile, .rex-profile {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.photo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
.info {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 225px;
}
.user-name {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 8px;
  width: 70px;
}
.name, .follow {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.description, .rating {
  color: rgb(96, 96, 96);
}
.follow-button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
button {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(2, 158, 255);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
button:active {
  opacity: 0.5;  
}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="list-of-friends">
     <div class="oliver-profile">
      <div class="profile-picture">
        <img class="photo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6DE-7qYRuIujluCF1GJzR5V-bGATSDTqtzw&usqp=CAU">
      </div>
     <div class="info">
    <div class="user-name">
      <p class="name">Oliver</p>
      <p class="description">The Cat</p>
      <p class="rating">Popular</p>
    </div>  
    <div class="follow-button">
      <button class="follow">Follow</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="mimi-profile">
      <div class="profile-picture">
        <img class="photo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTcr6E-AL2FTIOZmGKYOcs3sUDHA_CPqVhr3w&usqp=CAU">
      </div>
     <div class="info">
    <div class="user-name">
      <p class="name">Mimi</p>
      <p class="description">Sleepy Cat</p>
      <p class="rating">Popular</p>
    </div>  
    <div class="follow-button">
      <button class="follow">Follow</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="rex-profile">
      <div class="profile-picture">
        <img class="photo" src="https://d2zp5xs5cp8zlg.cloudfront.net/image-53920-800.jpg">
      </div>
     <div class="info">
    <div class="user-name">
      <p class="name">Rex</p>
      <p class="description">Happy Cat</p>
      <p class="rating">Popular</p>
    </div>  
    <div class="follow-button">
      <button class="follow">Follow</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: If your still stuck, I reommend posting these questions to reddit/other.  Stack Overflow is for questions that others could benifit off of (aswell as others). But on what to improve, I wouldn't say there's much. just a few gaps in you knowledge.

In the `button` style, you declare `padding-top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom`, where it could all be done in one style: `padding 8px 7px;`. Keep in mind that there's also a 4-argument variant `padding: top right bottom left;`. Maybe just scrollling through the HTML section in W3Schools could help.

ps. `follow-button` on line 15 is missing a `.`